# Isomorphism between Cartesian and Polar coordinates

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I have a homework problem that is explicitly stated as follows:

The set $C$ of the complex numbers can be defined in two different ways:

a. As a set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$
where $x,y∈R$

b. As a set of all ordered pairs $(ϕ,ρ)$
where $ϕ∈[0,2π)$ and $ρ>0$, and the pair $(0,0)$

Establish an isomorphism between these two sets, which will preserve the operation of addition and multiplication of complex numbers.

I asked this question (incorrectly) yesterday and the conclusion in the comments/answer was that the question was ill-posed. After talking to the course instructor (who was covering monoids, groups, semigroups, homomorphism, and isomorphism in that lecture), I was suggested to find a mapping $f$ such that $f$ preserved Cartesian and Polar addition, and that 'addition is harder than multiplication'. I made a new attempt and wanted to ask the community whether I made some significant progress.

I have two groups $G1$ and $G2$ of Cartesian and Polar ordered pairs respectively. Let me take the group operation for both groups to be addition, because I have to show that addition is preserved.

Then I have $f((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))=f((x_1,y_1))+f((x_2,y_2))$. What would a suitable $f$ be? The natural choice of $f$ is the mapping $f((x,y))=(arctan(\frac{y}{x}),\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. Then, we have $$f((x_1,y_1))+f((x_2,y_2))=(arctan(\frac{y_1}{x_1}),\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2})+(arctan(\frac{y_2}{x_2}),\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2})$$ and $$f((x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2))=f((x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2))=(arctan(\frac{y_1+y_2}{x_1+x_2},\sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2}))$$

While the formula for $arctan(a)+arctan(b)$ is well-known, it is easy to see that the terms under the radical signs do not agree. However, we 'know' that what we are doing is adding in polar coordinates, so it *should* work out 'intuitively' - but I'm not sure how to put it into words.

Any help would be appreciated!